# Difference Between Two-Factor and Two-Step Authentication

Tags: authentication

Difference Between Two-Factor and Two-Step Authentication? How it is different from each other with an example?

Answer (score 0):

In two-factor authentication the user will be required to provide information of two different types in order to identity themselves. Generally the types of information that will be required are a subset of the following:

- Knowledge: Something the user knows (e.g. a password)
- Possession: Something the user has (e.g. a physical key)
- Inheritance: Something the user is (e.g. a fingerprint or retina scan)

With two-step authentication, there's more than one thing the user will have to do, but it may be within the same type of information. For example, the user will provide a password and a pin. Both fall within the same type of information, something the user knows, but it still is a two-step procedure.

There's also the fact that **sometimes it can be argued that some approaches to two-factor authentication are not indeed two-factor and more like two-step**. I would say, the most debated discussions are around implementations based on cell phones, because even though a cell phone is something you have, sometimes you authenticate by reading a piece of information from the phone and in theory that means that it's actually something you know.

---

Having said that, and not wanting to a be a terminology purist, any means that provide additional protection besides just a password are a huge improvement. You can check [Getting started with Multifactor Authentication](https://auth0.com/learn/get-started-with-mfa/) for a further read.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between two factor authentication and two step authentication is method used to verify the user's identity.

Two Factor requires the user their password then another one time password 
This one time password is either a code received on their mobile device, or perhaps a code generated from an app like Google Authenticator.

Two Step Authentication requires the user to enter their password and the next step the user is in possession of the token or cookie on their computer
If the cookie or token doesn't exist - they are then have to enter a One Time Password that they receive via SMS, Email or use an Authenticator application.